# Changing reportviewer values in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an integer value stored in my database representing a document status.

I want to write a report that shows the status in one of the columns.

However, I don't want to show the raw integer value in the column. I want to show a string that transforms the status to a human-readable format.

eg:

```
1 -> New
2 -> Pending
3 -> Sent
```

This feels like it requires more than an expression - ie: C# code. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a lookup table? Where these statuses are stored?

Comment: They are stored in enums in my business objects. This is so that they can be localized.

Comment: nunespascal's solution looks decent enough to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also solve the problem by using a CASE in the query you use to select.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN Status = 1 THEN 'New'
  WHEN Status = 2 THEN 'Pending'
  WHEN Status = 3 THEN 'Sent'
END as "StatusStr"
FROM
...
;
```

Comment: Can this be done in code? I can certainly start off hardcoding the strig values like this but i want to be able to call my business layer to get the localized strings eventually.

Comment: I guess I'll post a follow up question for that.

Comment: Reports accept parameters. You could do the conversion in c# and just pass this as a parameter to the report.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing integer parameter to the report viewer and you want to transform it to some "string" you can assign expression for the column like

```
=IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, "New", IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 2, "Pending", "Sent"))
```